# Are there any difference between aspx and code behind when assigning text values asp.net 4.0 c#

Tags: asp.net, variables, code-behind, assign

This is code behind assigning  aspx.cs

```
      if (srLang == "tr")
    {
        lblUnWantedPrivateMessages.Text = "Özel Mesaj Almak İstemediğiniz Oyuncular";
        lblPmBlockUserNameTitle.Text = "Oyuncu Adı:";
    }
    else
    {
        lblUnWantedPrivateMessages.Text = "Players That You Don't Want To Receive PM";
        lblPmBlockUserNameTitle.Text = "Player Name:";
    }
```

and this is aspx assigning

```
    <%    
    if (srLang == "tr")
    {
        lblUnWantedPrivateMessages.Text = "Özel Mesaj Almak İstemediğiniz Oyuncular";
        lblPmBlockUserNameTitle.Text = "Oyuncu Adı:";
    }
    else
    {
        lblUnWantedPrivateMessages.Text = "Players That You Don't Want To Receive PM";
        lblPmBlockUserNameTitle.Text = "Player Name:";
    }
     %>
```

Are there any performance difference between these 2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both will compile into equivalent code, and there will be no performance difference.

Placing significant code in the code behind file allows for a separation of responsibilities (display markup in the aspx file, logic in the code behind file) and leads to code that is easier to maintain.